# Google books jquery autocomplete from api url call json not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete, google-books

I have a search box, findBook, and I'm trying to use the jquery autocomplete with json api call to google-books api to display book title, author and thumbnail.

When I type in the search box nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated. The source for the autocomplete is the google-boosk api url. Thanks :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Your web-app is https, so your scripts need to be too -->


<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/home.css" type="text/css">

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js'
        integrity="sha256-gvQgAFzTH6trSrAWoH1iPo9Xc96QxSZ3feW6kem+O00="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script type='text/javascript'>

</script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#findBook").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {

                $.ajax({
                    method:"GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + request.term,


                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        var transformed = $.map(data.items.volumeInfo, function (book) {
                            return {
                                title: book.title,
                                author: book.author,
                                image: book.imageLinks.thumbnail
                            };
                        });

                        response(transformed);
                    },

                    error: function () {

                        response([]);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });

 </script>


</head>
<body>


 <div class="searchBook">



   <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="findBook" />


</div>



  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`$.map()`**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) jQuery function requires an array to iterate. In your case: `data.items.volumeInfo` is `undefined`.

However, you can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) JavaScript function to iterate over `data.items`, in this way:

```
var transformed = data.items.map(function(book) {
  return {
    title: book.volumeInfo.title,
    author: book.volumeInfo.authors,
    image: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail
  };
});
```

In the above code, the book object has a `volumeInfo` attribute, so yo can access its attributes to build a new object, in this case **`transformed`** variable.

Now, to show the book title, author and the thumbnail, you will have to modify the rendered HTML of jQuery autocomplete plugin, using the `_renderItem` function.

Something like this function:

```
.autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
  return $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<a>" + "<img src=\"" + item.image + "\" style=\"height: 40%;\" /><br />" + (item.author && item.author.length ? item.author.map(function(x) {
      return x;
    }).join(" | ") : '') + " - " + item.title + "</a>")
    .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Getting this result:

[image]

See in this example:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#findBook").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + request.term,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          term: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
          var transformed = data.items.map(function(book) {
            return {
              title: book.volumeInfo.title,
              author: book.volumeInfo.authors,
              image: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail
            };
          });
          response(transformed);
        }
      });
    }
  }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
      .data("item.autocomplete", item)
      .append("<a>" + "<img src=\"" + item.image + "\" style=\"height: 40%;\" /><br />" + (item.author && item.author.length ? item.author.map(function(x) {
        return x;
      }).join(" | ") : '') + " - " + item.title + "</a>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote JSONP datasource</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="searchBook">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="findBook">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Remember to avoid mixing different versions of the jQuery library.

**Update:** To show only the image.

The options are rendered by default, **if they have text to display**. However, we can add a hidden `span` with the text, where it would only be showing the image.

Something like in this example:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#findBook").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + request.term,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          term: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
          var transformed = data.items.map(function(book) {
            return {
              title: book.volumeInfo.title,
              author: book.volumeInfo.authors,
              image: book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail
            };
          });
          response(transformed);
        }
      });
    }
  }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
      .data("item.autocomplete", item)
      .append("<img src=\"" + item.image + "\" style=\"height: 40%;\" /><span hidden>" + item.image + "</span>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote JSONP datasource</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="searchBook">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="findBook">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I modify the code if I only want to display the book images and leave out the title?

Comment: .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a><img src='" + item.image + "' />" +  "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);


            };

Comment: Hey Danny, I have a new question about the autocomplete menu. Can you take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60960731/submit-data-from-textbox-or-jquery-autocomplete-menu

Answer (score 0):

You are loading two diferents jQuery versions `jquery-2.2.4` and `jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js` and the version 3 it's loading after the `jquery UI`. Thats the issue.

I Just remove the `jquery-2x` and move the `jquery3x` before the `jquery UI`. In fact should be work if you just move the `jquery-3x` before the `jquery-UI` whitout removing anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Your web-app is https, so your scripts need to be too -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/home.css" type="text/css">
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#findBook").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {

                $.ajax({
                    method:"GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + request.term,


                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        var transformed = $.map(data.items.volumeInfo, function (book) {
                            return {
                                title: book.title,
                                author: book.author,
                                image: book.imageLinks.thumbnail
                            };
                        });

                        response(transformed);
                    },

                    error: function () {

                        response([]);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="searchBook">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="findBook" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: example here]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. So all the versions of jquery and jquery-ui  should be 2.2.4 or 1.12.1? Your response had both.

Comment: I update my answer to try to improve the explanation. About jquery UI support the jquery version >=1.7.0 <4.0.0